# How to export canvas to HTML in Fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

Is there a way to export a canvas element with multiple objects to html with javascript code using fabricjs?I know i can export toJSON or toObject but this isnt HTML.

I found that http://canvimation.github.com/ has a function(file>export canvas to html) to export a canvas drawing to native html code.Is that possible with fabricjs?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'export a canvas to html': `<canvas>` is an html entity...

Comment: go to http://canvimation.github.com/ and try it.You draw something on canvimation then click file>"export canvas to html" and that opens a new window that shows the drawing in native html code without the canvimation library.

Comment: I see! I've done a few tricks with canvas exporting recently. What do you want to do *with* the "html export" once it's exported: save it, insert it into another web page, etc?

Edit: I ask because all that Export as HTML function does in the above example is grab the `<canvas>` object and stick it into a new window without the interface decorations. If you want to manipulate the image, or view it locally, you could export it as an SVG.

Comment: I want to be able to manipulate some objects fillstyle color.Fabricjs documentation isnt very helpful.I want to create some canvas drawings with something like fabricjs kitchensink and then save the drawing for later manipulation of the color of some of its objects.For example i want to draw a street on kitchensink with trafic lights ,save it somehow and then recall somewhere else and change the color of its traffic lights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fabric only supports export to (its own) **object representation**, **JSON** (basically a serialization of that object representation), and **SVG**.

If your goal is to create something in fabric, then export it for use in environment that doesn't support canvas, then maybe you can use SVG — as long as SVG is supported in that environment.

You also have to understand that there's no such thing as "native html code". There are different versions of HTML — HTML4, HTML5, etc. Canvas is considered to be [part of current HTML standard (HTML5)](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html). So drawing something on canvas could definitely be considered "using native html code" ;)

If you want recreate fabric rendering without canvas **and without SVG** then there's really nothing fabric can help with. It would be unnecessarily complicated to try to provide canvas-less rendering of complex SVG shapes, images (under various transformations, like scaling/rotation), and other objects.

Comment: Let's say i create a new polygon and put it on a variable.    var arrow=fabric.Polygon(points,{fill:"red",left:1,top:1}) .I can then use    arrow.set(fill:"green")  to change the fill color.The problem is when i run    var js = JSON.stringify(canvas); 
  canvas.clear();
  canvas.loadFromJSON(js);    after clearing the canvas and load the JSON string i cannot change the color anymore with arrow.set(fill:"green").

Comment: So is there a way i can save the variable that is connected with the object on the json string?How can i pass an "id" inside the object's json represantation so i can recall it after loading the json to address specific objects on the reloaded canvas?

Comment: Yes, `arrow` no longer refers to an object on canvas after you re-loaded canvas from JSON. At that point fabric created a new set of objects. If it's the only item on canvas — of if you know its "index" — you can retrieve it via `canvas.item(0)` (or `canvas.item(index)`). Otherwise, I guess you would need to extend `toJSON` output ([see how](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/Adding-additional-object-properties-to-serialized-JSON)) to return some kind of unique id.

Comment: thank you kangax.I extended json output like in the tutorial with an "id" property.After i loadfromJson i reassign the variables based on the id.The answer given in the comments is correct but my question is bad so i'll tick it as answered.thank you again

Comment: @kangax I found a pure HTML canvas save to image example. I still don't quite understand why FabricJS is not able to do this while it can save as SVG and JSON.

Comment: Is there a way i could convert the JSON to a HTML file format to load the same fabric canvas elements?